# SpringDoc with Spring Webflux functional endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, openapi, springdoc

I'm using Spring Webfluxs' [functional endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) and would like to generate an openAPI definition for it.

I added [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org/#spring-webflux-support), but the resulting openAPI definition is empty:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {},
  "components": {}
}
```

Endpoints are defined like

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class Routers {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> uploadRoute(UploadHandler uploadHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(POST("/api/upload").and(accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)), uploadHandler::handleUploadedFiles);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to derive an openAPI definition from Springs' functional endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use, functional DSL or the `@RouterOperations` annotations.

More details are available in this section of [springdoc-openapi documentation](https://springdoc.org/#selecting-the-rest-controllers-to-include-in-the-documentation).

This sample code shows is a demo code, for how functional endpoints are supported:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webflux-functional